# clone recovery partition from usb drive to d: drive windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, partitioning, hard-drive-recovery

I created a USB recovery drive using windows 10 tool in order to Back up system files to the recovery drive.
Then when I was asked to empty D: from my PC in order to recover space I answered yes.

But now I'd like to have again my D: drive filled with the recovery files as originally were.

So I am asking if it is possible to move from the USB recovery drive to D:  on my windows 10 pc?
How? Simply copying?

Many thanks.

Comment: Where exactly did you store the recovery images of the partition you deleted? If you deleted the partition that contain the recovery images, then they are gone, since you deleted the partition. Your question is difficult to understand.

Comment: I didn't delete the partition but the content. I stored in a USB pendrive.

Comment: You indicated you deleted a partition: “Then when I was asked to delete D: from my PC in order to recover space I answered yes.”, what did you mean by that?  [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I edited the original post as you wrote.